# Change Jmeter Threads Pool size

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

In response data, I am getting an error message. 
I want to increse pool size from 10 to 100!.

```
{
    "errorCode": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
    "message": "Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@428373db rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@7114477d[Running, pool size = 10, active threads = 10, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 30014]"
}
```

Comment: Stuff like **urgent** in here only triggers some of us sarcastic users to say something like "when is the deadline". Especially when the question shows 0 efforts. However, I'm not gonna do that

Answer (score 1):

Let's see, from [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> **Core and maximum pool sizes**
> A `ThreadPoolExecutor` will automatically adjust the pool size (see `getPoolSize()`) according to the bounds set by `corePoolSize` (see `getCorePoolSize()`) and `maximumPoolSize` (see `getMaximumPoolSize()`). When a new task is submitted in method execute(`java.lang.Runnable`), and fewer than `corePoolSize` threads are running, a new thread is created to handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle. If there are more than `corePoolSize` but less than `maximumPoolSize` threads running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is full. By setting `corePoolSize` and `maximumPoolSize` the same, you create a fixed-size thread pool. **By setting `maximumPoolSize` to an essentially unbounded value such as `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, you allow the pool to accommodate an arbitrary number of concurrent tasks. Most typically, core and maximum pool sizes are set only upon construction, but they may also be changed dynamically using `setCorePoolSize(int)` and `setMaximumPoolSize(int)`.**

So, use the [`setMaximumPoolSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setMaximumPoolSize(int)) method with the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` value as an argument.

Here are [some samples to guide you around](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor&method=setMaximumPoolSize).